# When did disciples go to Galilee to meet Jesus?

Tags: matthew, luke

In gospel of matthew story ended with disciples went to Galilee and Jesus announced The  Great  Commission

> Then the eleven disciples went to Galilee, to the mountain where Jesus had told them to go.(matthew 28：16）

But gospel of luke said that Jesus met disciples and asked them to stay in Jerusalem until he sent what Father has promised

> I am going to send you what my Father has promised; but stay in the city until you have been clothed with power from on high.(luke 24:49)

And it seemed like it was the same day Jesus was risen because it was not a long time since two disciples saw Jesus on the road to Emmaus and it was the same day.

> Now that same day two of them were going to a village called Emmaus, about seven miles from Jerusalem.(luke 24:13)

So according to these above it seemed like it was impossible for disciples to go to Galilee before this meeting in gospel of luke. It was certain that disciples stayed in Jerusalem after Jesus was taken up to heaven. Maybe they left Jerusalem later between the meeting and ascension because Jesus told them? At the same time John also recorded John himself and Peter met Jesus after resurrection in John 21. But I am not very certain about this. I hope someone can answear this qustion.

Answer (score 2):

Let us be very clear about what happened.  After Jesus rose from the grave, He appeared to many for a period of 40 days:

> Acts 1:3 - After His suffering, He presented Himself to them with many
> convincing proofs that He was alive. He appeared to them over a span
> of forty days and spoke about the kingdom of God.

This is the same author as the Gospel of Luke.  Thus, after Jesus rose from the grave it was 40 days before He finally ascended to heaven.  This was just 10 days before Pentecost as recorded in Acts 2.

Thus, Matt 28 covers this time period of 40 days as does Luke 24.  Jesus met various people at various times in Jerusalem, on the mountain, on the road to Emmaus, etc.  His final appearance loaction is not stated except to record that He lead the disciples as far as Bethany (Luke 24:50) from where He arose to heaven and told the disciples what is recorded in Luke 24:49 -

> And behold, I am sending the promise of My Father upon you. But remain
> in the city until you have been clothed with power from on high.

Answer (score 0):

> Luke 24:12 Peter, however, got up and ran to the **tomb**. And after bending down and seeing only the linen cloths, he went away, wondering to himself what had happened.
>
> 13 **That same day** two of them were going to a village called **Emmaus**, about seven miles from Jerusalem.

So, Emmaus happened first right after the tomb visit.

> Matthew 28:12 When the chief priests had met with the elders and devised a plan, they gave the **soldiers** a large sum of money, 13telling them, “You are to say, ‘His disciples came during the night and stole him away while we were asleep.’ 14If this **report** gets to the governor, we will satisfy him and keep you out of trouble.” 15So the soldiers took the money and did as they were instructed. And this story has been widely circulated among the Jews to this very day.
>
> 16 Then the eleven disciples went to **Galilee**, to the **mountain** where Jesus had told them to go.

Galilean mountain was next after the tomb soldiers' false report.

Now, resuming Luke's description in verse

> 32 They asked each other, “Were not our hearts burning within us as He spoke with us on the road and opened the Scriptures to us?” 33And they got up that very hour and returned to Jerusalem.
>
> There they found the Eleven and those with them, gathered together 34and saying, “The Lord has indeed risen and has appeared to **Simon**!”

That was Simon Peter, 1 Corinthians 15:5

> and that he appeared to Cephas, and then to the Twelve.

By the time they found the Eleven, some substantial time had already passed.

> 35 Then the two told what had happened on the way, and how Jesus was recognized by them when he broke the bread.
>
> 36 While they were still talking about this, Jesus himself stood among them and said to them, “Peace be with you.”

By now Jesus had showed himself to more disciples.
Staying in the city happened at this point.

> 45 Then he opened their minds so they could understand the Scriptures. 46He told them, “This is what is written: The Messiah will suffer and rise from the dead on the third day, 47and repentance for the forgiveness of sins will be preached in his name to all nations, beginning at Jerusalem. 48You are witnesses of these things. 49I am going to send you what my Father has promised; **but stay in the city** until you have been clothed with power from on high.”

The sequence of events:

1. Emmaus
2. Galilean mountain
3. Staying in Jerusalem

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>**Matthew 28:5**</sup> And the angel answered and said unto the women: <sup>**28:7**</sup> ***Go quickly**, and tell his disciples that he is risen from the dead; and, behold, he goeth before you into **Galilee**; there shall ye see him: lo, I have told you.* <sup>**28:10**</sup> Then said Jesus unto them: *Be not afraid: go tell my brethren that they go into **Galilee**, and there shall they see me.* <sup>**28:16**</sup> Then the eleven disciples went away into **Galilee**, into a **mountain** where Jesus had appointed them.

---

> <sup>**Luke 24:4**</sup> Two men stood by them in shining garments: <sup>**24:5**</sup> They said unto them: <sup>**24:6**</sup> *He is not here, but is risen: remember how he spake unto you when he was yet in **Galilee**.* <sup>**24:36**</sup> And as they thus spake, Jesus himself stood in the midst of them, and saith unto them: <sup>**24:49**</sup> *Behold, I send the promise of my Father upon you: but **tarry ye in** the city of **Jerusalem**, until ye be endued with power from on high.*

> <sup>**Acts 1:1**</sup> Jesus, <sup>**1:4**</sup> being assembled together with them, commanded them that they should **not depart from Jerusalem**, but wait for the promise of the Father, which, saith he, ye have heard of me. <sup>**1:12**</sup> Then returned they unto **Jerusalem** from the **mount called [Olivet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_of_Olives)**, which is from **Jerusalem** a sabbath day's journey.

---

As can be seen, both notions (*Galilee* and the *mountain*) are mentioned by both Evangelists, but the details and circumstances differ.